# Setting `checked` property of Checkbox Toggle Component

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm working on a checkbox component who's styling depends on the checked status of the checkbox. This works fine when the user clicks the checkbox, but if it's set manually, that property gets overridden.

component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function IconCheck({children}) {

const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

return(
  <span className="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label className={`btn ${checkSize} ${isChecked ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-primary"}`}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => setIsChecked((prev) => !prev)}
        checked={isChecked}
      />
      {children}
    </label>
  </span>
)
}
```

story:

```
<IconCheck>Default</IconCheck>
<IconCheck isChecked>Should be Checked</IconCheck>
```

I believe this has to do with the useState, but I'm not sure what change is needed. Any tips?

Comment: what do you mean by "if it's set manually"?

Comment: @MrBens In a typical checkbox, if I set the `checked=true`, it will be checked. In the above instance, setting `isChecked` to true in the instance gets overridden/ignored.

Comment: please post the full component, I think you're confusing your props with state...

Comment: @MrBens Rest of the component has been added to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing `props` with `state`. You probably want your component to begin with a default value, and than control this value using `useState`, so here is one way to do it by accepting `defaultValue` prop for the component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function IconCheck({ children, defaultValue }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(defaultValue);

  return(
    <span className="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => setIsChecked((prev) => !prev)}
            checked={isChecked}
          />
          {children}
        </label>
    </span>
  )
}
```

Then in the parent component you call

```
<IconCheck defaultValue={true}>Should be checked</IconCheck>
```

Answer (score 0):

- get prop isCheckedProp
- useState( isCheckedProp|| false ,);
  or more proffesional using useEffect

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. How do I apply this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).